# VSCode html-files formatter not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with intellisense
I have disabled all extensions, but I still get:

> sorry, but there is no formatter for html-files installed

any idea?

VS Code version 1.19.1

```
// Enable/disable autoclosing of HTML tags.
"html.autoClosingTags": true,

// List of tags, comma separated, where the content shouldn't be reformatted. 'null' defaults to the 'pre' tag.
"html.format.contentUnformatted": "pre,code,textarea",

// Enable/disable default HTML formatter
"html.format.enable": true,

// End with a newline.
"html.format.endWithNewline": false,

// List of tags, comma separated, that should have an extra newline before them. 'null' defaults to "head, body, /html".
"html.format.extraLiners": "head, body, /html",

// Format and indent {{#foo}} and {{/foo}}.
"html.format.indentHandlebars": false,

// Indent <head> and <body> sections.
"html.format.indentInnerHtml": false,

// Maximum number of line breaks to be preserved in one chunk. Use 'null' for unlimited.
"html.format.maxPreserveNewLines": null,

// Whether existing line breaks before elements should be preserved. Only works before elements, not inside tags or for text.
"html.format.preserveNewLines": true,

// List of tags, comma separated, that shouldn't be reformatted. 'null' defaults to all tags listed at https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content.
"html.format.unformatted": "wbr",

// Wrap attributes.
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "auto",

// Maximum amount of characters per line (0 = disable).
"html.format.wrapLineLength": 120,

// Configures if the built-in HTML language support suggests Angular V1 tags and properties.
"html.suggest.angular1": true,

// Configures if the built-in HTML language support suggests HTML5 tags, properties and values.
"html.suggest.html5": true,

// Configures if the built-in HTML language support suggests Ionic tags, properties and values.
"html.suggest.ionic": true,

// Traces the communication between VS Code and the HTML language server.
"html.trace.server": "off",

// Configures if the built-in HTML language support validates embedded scripts.
"html.validate.scripts": true,

// Configures if the built-in HTML language support validates embedded styles.
"html.validate.styles": true,
```

Thanks

Comment: Settings look fine! Can you uninstall and reinstall VSCode?

Comment: yes I had, but funny I solved the problem by switching my current open project and switching it back

Comment: also I have noticed that in <script> is not working

Comment: If you're having persistent problems with your VSCode installation, it might be worth submitting a bug so that the team can look into it and hopefully fix the issues. Click on the Smiley face in the right bottom corner of your VSC window, and then click on "Submit a Bug." This will open a "New Issue" window on their Github page, filled with necessary information about your installation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with VSC version 1.30. These steps solved my problem:

1. Press `Ctrl+K Ctrl+O` to select the folder in which the html file lies.
2. Open the File Explorer `Ctrl+Shift+E` and open the html file
3. Press `Ctrl+Shift+I`.

Viola! I got the formatted code

Comment: This actually worked... and it solved a lot of other problems I was having... mainly VS Code not auto closing my tags. Thank you!

Comment: This is solution!

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this I was working with a single html file that was not in an opened folder nor VSC workspace.  When I setup a workspace that included the file, the html formatter worked.

Comment: Thanks, saving a workspace fixed this immediately for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I had multiple formatters installed and I needed to configure which formatter to use. I ended up just uninstalling the one I didn't want anymore and it went back to working.